# Trying to click on button gives me an error. I am using repl.it python environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, replit

Code:

```
from webbot import Browser
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

web = Browser()

tab = 1
add = 1

web.go_to('https://tankster.io')
time.sleep(1)

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Boss vs Boss')]")
button[0].click()

text_areas = web.find_elements(xpath='//input')
web.type(web.Key.ENTER,into=text_areas[0].text)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 22, in <module>
    button[0].click()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am running a repl.it python environment and trying to get selenium to click on a button for me, that seems to give the error since it works fine without any selenium additions to the previous code I had. :)

Comment: print button and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to happen because `button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Boss vs Boss')]")`
Must return to you an empty list. Here is an example of that in play.

```
x = []
print(x[0])
```

Error

````
    print(x[0])
IndexError: list index out of range```
````